# Fedora Remove All Packages but Base Install

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I have bloated my system with unnecessary packages and want to "start from zero". Rather than reinstalling I would prefer to do it from the OS and do it live.

How do I remove all packages not in base install?

Some relevant things that didn't quite pan out https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8646/erase-all-packages-except-a-given-list-of-packagesgroups/
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_tips#Removing_everything_but_base_group

Edit: to clarify using dnf

Comment: Most useful thing I have found so far is rpmreaper. Really useful for cleaning up so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the original `/root/install.log` you can follow [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/58146/216364) to compare the originally-installed and subsequently-installed packages.  If not, you will need to pull a list of base packages off your install-media and perform a similar comparison.

Comment: File doesn't exist. ;_;

Comment: another option is using    ' /root/anaconda-ks.cfg '  it has the "'Groups" and any single packages installed  at initial you can run rpm list installed |grep -v $(all those groups /packages) which gives you a naked initial install

Comment: Ok, so second part of you answer, javabrett, was the one that helped, thanks. C: