# how do you get a history of the packages you've installed in ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you track which packages were installed on Ubuntu (Linux)?](https://superuser.com/questions/6338/how-do-you-track-which-packages-were-installed-on-ubuntu-linux)

the question in the title is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

From SuperUser:
[How do you track which packages were installed on Ubuntu (Linux)?](https://superuser.com/questions/6338/how-do-you-track-which-packages-were-installed-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: thx tom, this is perfect. I guess I need to start looking there for these types of questions

Comment: np.  always glad to help.