# backup linux that installed inside windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, wubi

I have Ubuntu 10.04 inside Windows Vista.
I'm going to install Windows 7 but I don't want to lose all the software I have downloaded.
How can I backup my Linux on an external device (HDD, DVD ...) and take it back to my hard-disk (I want to install it outside the Windows if possible)?
Is there any software that can do this for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "inside Windows Vista", and by "install it outside the Windows"? Have you installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine?

There are ways to store a list of all software packages you have installed, if that is what you want.

Comment: @Genba:I have installed it inside windows.Ubuntu asks for it if you start the installer inside windows.http://ubuntumanual.org/files/u1/ubuntu_cd_menu.png

Comment: @Hello71:yes.  and I've done it using APTonCD.it is really cool and amazingly fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how you could back up your Ubuntu-in-Windows installation, but it may be useful to have a list of all installed packages in order to reinstall them without the need to select every package one by one. This way you can simply get a list of all installed packages and tell deselect/apt-get/Synaptic to automatically install all of them. Take a look at these links:

- [Ubuntu Tricks - how to generate a list of installed packages and use it to reinstall packages](http://www.arsgeek.com/2006/09/19/ubuntu-tricks-how-to-generate-a-list-of-installed-packages-and-use-it-to-reinstall-packages/)
- [How to list manually installed software packages in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/132614/how-to-list-manually-installed-software-packages-in-ubuntu)
- [How do you track which packages were installed on Ubuntu (Linux)?](https://superuser.com/questions/6338/how-do-you-track-which-packages-were-installed-on-ubuntu-linux)

In addition, if you want to store all packages in a CD/DVD, so that you do not have to download all packages again, you can use [APTonCD](http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/).

If you also want to back up your data, you will have to do extra work.

And I guess that, if you want to install Ubuntu in a partition on your hard drive, you will have to repeat the installation process from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Method of taking the back-up of all the installed packages in an Ubuntu machine
Src: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=819396

Ignore the warning:

```
dpkg-deb: ignoring 1 warnings about the control file(s) warning, './dpkg-repack-20691/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field 'Original-Maintainer'
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack fakeroot
mkdir ~/dpkg-repack; cd ~/dpkg-repack
fakeroot -u dpkg-repack `dpkg --get-selections | grep install | cut -f1`
```

Get inside the backed up folder and run the installation command!

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: This one is really cool.and I'm having a debian machine right now.

Answer (score 0):

In short, copy the files in :\ubuntu\disks to a backup location, then reinstall Wubi and copy the files back. (Reinstalling is necessary to overwrite the bootloader to allow booting from Wubi.)