# Linux: Compare packages

Tags: linux, package-management

Is there a simple way to compare all the current installed packages to the defaults (a fresh/clean installation)? So that I can see what packages I removed and which packages I manually installed?

I know Synaptics has a 'History' option, but it's nothing more than a log-file. And it also shows many  packages that were installed automaticly by updating the system.

Comment: That depends on your package manager. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Ranon Synaptics

Comment: Have a look here (applies to `aptitude`): http://superuser.com/questions/132614/how-to-list-manually-installed-software-packages-in-ubuntu/132624#132624